# is it possible to add custom a javascript tag to my facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to add a Javascript script to my facebook page. It's supposed to load the script from my domain, and the script will gather some info about the users and send it to my backend with JSONP.

Does facebook allow this, and if so how do you add your own tag in facebook?

I suppose this is a basic question - but I could't find the answer googling around or on SO.

Thanks,

--EDIT--

Found [this](https://woobox.com/customtab) - It looks like a tool for inserting an external iframe, that can contain JS, CSS etc. I'll see if this is usable..

Comment: You can't add anything like that to your Facebook profile since it could be a huge problem to let users do that due to other malicious users. You'll have to use whatever analytics Facebook gives you to figure out who's visiting your page.

Comment: @josh - What I want is more along the lines of google analytics - I have my own stuff I wrote... Is there any way of adding that to a page - custom tag/tab/iframe whatever?

Comment: I dont think so, but you can create a GreaseMonkey script and ask users to test it.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to create a Canvas app that loads your content, and then add it as a Page tab.